# getElementsByName() returns undefined

Tags: javascript

here is my basic code. I just need to print the value entered by the user. However, it returns undefined. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Script

```
// using getElementsByName() method
function msg(){
var v=document.getElementsByName("name1");
alert("Your name is:"+v[0].innerHTML);
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="name1"/>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="msg()"/>
```

Comment: It works correctly here, although, if you read innerHTML you are going to get empty string. getElementsByName does in deed return undefined it must be a browser specific issue. What browser are you using? (tested on most recent Opera, Firefox, Chrome and IE for Windows 8.1 at date).

Comment: use `value` instead of `innerHTML`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the misuse of innerHTML

Answer (score 7):

Use `.value`, instead of `.innerHTML`...

`.getElementsByName()` returns what you expect, your problem is the (miss)use of `innerHTML`.

```
// using getElementsByName() method
function msg() {
    var v = document.getElementsByName("name1");
    alert("Your name is:" + v[0].value);
}
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8YaHU/)

Answer (score 2):

I just ran your code, and it doesn't appear to return undefined. In fact, your getElementsByName returns the correct object. The problem is your alert statement.

You have:

```
alert("Your name is:"+v[0].innerHTML);
```

Should be:

```
alert("Your name is:"+v[0].value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `value` instead of `innerHTML`

`document.getElementsByName()` returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of all the elements with a given value for the name attribute.

So use like `alert("Your name is:"+v[0].value);`

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName

Answer (score -1):

use this code

```
<script>
function msg(){
var v=document.getElementsByName("name1");
alert(v);
 alert("Your name is:"+v[0].value);
}
</script>
```